# string containing comma(,) is not populated

Tags: php, string, escaping

i am trying to display address that contains commas(,) but the problem is after first comma address in not populating.
my code-

```
<td class="content"><input name="txtShippingAddress2" type="text" class="box" id="txtShippingAddress2" size="40" maxlength="100" 
        value=<?php echo $Address; ?> ></td>
```

my address in DB = '23 Awe, Charls street'
but it is displaying only '23 Awe'  if i remove comma it will display whole address. 
what shoul i do?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is un-answerable in its current format - you need to provide more surrounding code and explain the issue you're having in more detail.

Comment: @midd I have my question updated

Comment: Are you echoing that in a blank sourrounding or you have something else before and after the echo? And $address is taken directly from the DB or passes through some function or other possible manipulations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put quotes before the `<?php` and after the `?>`:

`value="<?php echo $Address; ?>"`